# How to render Symfony form with dynamic number of checkboxes. The list of items(checkboxes) is placed in dynamic .json file

Tags: php, arrays, json, symfony, symfony-3.3

I am trying to figure out how to render form with dynamic checkboxes. 
Those checkboxes should be implemented in dynamic way , because the number of them depends on items(options) placed in external .json file.

Any ideas? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CallbackChoiceLoader` was introduced with Symfony 3.2+.

In order to load your choices from a JSON-file you could do the following:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\ChoiceList\Loader\CallbackChoiceLoader;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;

$builder->add('constants', ChoiceType::class, [
    'multiple' => true, 
    'expanded' => true, // render checkboxes
    'choice_loader' => new CallbackChoiceLoader(function() {
         $file = '/path/to/choices.json'; 
         $jsonString = file_get_contents($file);
         $choiceArray = json_decode($jsonString, true);

         return $choiceArray;
    },
]);
```

Comment: elegant for lazy loading! +1 :)

Comment: Thanks for the edit - i forgot the to add the `expanded` option :)